# ImageMagic requires Ghostscript to run in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert a pdf file into an image and it worked fine. However, i have to install ghostscript for it to run.
Is there a way I can copy the DLLs required without installing ghostscript?
Like is there a c# wrapper for ghostscript and if so, how can I make use of it?
Here's my code:

```
 public ActionResult UploadPdf(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            byte[] ss = fileStream.ToArray();
            MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            settings.Density = new Density(100, 100);
            List<ImageModel> model = new List<ImageModel>();
            using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
                images.Read(ss, settings); // Read PDF file
                MemoryStream convertedFile;
                foreach (MagickImage image in images)
                {
                    convertedFile = new MemoryStream();
                    ImageModel innerModle = new ImageModel();
                    image.Write(convertedFile, MagickFormat.Png);
                    byte[] byteArray = convertedFile.ToArray();
                    innerModle.Images = byteArray;
                    model.Add(innerModle);
                    convertedFile.Flush();
                    convertedFile.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

View model:

```
 public class ImageModel
    {
        public byte[] Images{ get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<DocumentViewerPoc.Models.ImageModel>


<h2>UploadPdf</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Images);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
    <img src="@imgSrc" />
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Will keep that in mind thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great answer in the documentation of Magick.NET (that I wrote).

You only need to install Ghostscript if you want to convert EPS/PDF/PS files. Make sure you only install the version of GhostScript with the same platform. If you use the 64-bit version of Magick.NET you should also install the 64-bit version of Ghostscript. You can use the 32-bit version together with the 64-version but you will get a better performance if you keep the platforms the same. Ghostscript can be downloaded here: http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html. If you don't want to install Ghostscript on your machine you can copy gsdll32.dll/gsdl64.dll and gswin32c.exe/gswin64c.exe to your server and tell Magick.NET where the file is located with the code below.

```
MagickNET.SetGhostscriptDirectory(@"C:\MyProgram\Ghostscript");
```

Be aware that you need a license if you want to use Ghostscript commercially.

Answer (score 0):

There's Ghostscript.NET and ghostscript sharp. Note that if you are intending to distribute the application and use either of these you will need to open source your application as well, under the terms of the AGPL, or seek a commercial license.